# What do these statements mean in CSS(twitter-Bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It's been weeks since I study CSS, but I still can't fully understand the statement below. 
I think it's a media query, but if I remove this from the CSS code, it cause the failure of the grid system.
Forgive me for didn't leaning English well.:)

```
@media print {
/*...*/;
}

*,*:before,*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Original code:

```
@media print {
    * {
        text-shadow: none !important;
        color: #000 !important;
        background: transparent !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }

    a,a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a[href]:after {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    }

    abbr[title]:after {
        content: " (" attr(title) ")";
    }

    a[href^="javascript:"]:after,a[href^="#"]:after {
        content: "";
    }

    pre,blockquote {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }

    tr,img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }
       @    page {
        margin: 2cm .5cm;
    }

    p,h2,h3 {
        orphans: 3;
        widows: 3;
    }

    h2,h3 {
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }

    .navbar {
        display: none;
    }

    .table td,.table th {
        background-color: #fff !important;
    }

    .btn>.caret,.dropup>.btn>.caret {
        border-top-color: #000 !important;
    }

    .label {
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .table {
        border-collapse: collapse !important;
    }

    .table-bordered th,.table-bordered td {
        border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
    }
}

*,*:before,*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: You are correct, it is a media query. Here is a link explaining it further: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: I formatted & indented your code properly, please dont paste code blocks, it gives me headaches :( For future ref: http://cssbeautify.com/

Comment: Sorry @ExtPro - looks like you and I were editing this one at the same time.  Your edit is undoubtedly far better, hopefully I've not just overwritten you!

Comment: @johnkavanagh Not at all, glad I wasn't the only one finding it painful to look at :)

Comment: `@media print{}` It`s used when your tempting to print a document, targeting different elements and properties within them.

Answer (score 0):

The chunk you have identified is a [print media query](http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/) which defines how the page should be styled if someone opts to print it.

Deleting this block on it's own won't do anything to how your pages appear in-browser.

At the very bottom (and outside of the print media query is this):

```css
*,*:before,*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I expect that it's deleting this that is causing the grid to break.

This resets the box model so that the width and height determine the border-box of the element (padding and border included in the width/height values).  Any padding or border specified on the element is laid out and drawn inside this specified width and height.

The content width and height are calculated by subtracting the border and padding widths of the respective sides from the specified 'width' and 'height' properties.

Reference is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
*,*:before,*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Removing that bit of code is what is causing your grid to fail. This system changes the traditional box model of CSS to the border-box model. What exactly does that mean?

Say you have a `div` that you want to give some padding and a border to.

### Traditional

Setting your width to 200px, left and right padding to 20px, and a 2px border will result in a `div` that will render 244px wide with a 200px content area. The way to get it to render at 200 is to subtract the border and the padding from the width (or height).

### border-box

Setting `box-sizing: border-box` takes any padding and border *off* of the set width of the element, instead of adding to it. So your `div` in the previous example will render at 200px with a 156px content area, no adjustments needed.

The grid breaks because - when you remove this bit of code - you change back to the traditional model, which is doing the math on your `col` `div`s a completely different way.

### Further reading

If you want to know more, I would suggest you check out [Chris Coyier's take on this subject](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/), or just do a general search on `box-sizing: border-box` and you will find your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The bulk of the code you've posted is indeed a media query (for `print`, so will only apply when the page is printed).

However the last chunk of code -- is **not** part of that media query, and thus always applies. This is the important bit.

This bit of code sets `box-sizing: border-box` for all elements, and as you've discovered, it is pretty important for Bootstrap's grid system.

Setting `border-box` tells the browser that the element's `width` setting should include the border. Without this setting, borders are defined as being outside of the element.

This means that if you have (for example) two elements, each being set to `width:50%` and with a 1px border, with `border-box` in use, they would indeed take up a total of 100% of the width.

However without `border-box`, they take up 100% width plus 4px (1px for each of the 4 left/right borders between the two elements), and thus breaks out of the layout.